# Conflicting trait implementation despite type restriction

Tags: rust, type-conversion

Consider the following:

```rust
struct Foo(f32);

impl<T> std::convert::From<T> for Foo
where f32: std::convert::From<T>
{
    fn from(value : T) -> Self {
        Self(value.into())
    }
}

fn main() {
    let a: Foo = 42.into();
}
```

This of course doesn't work because

> the trait bound `f32: From<i32>` is not satisfied

So I'm trying to add another trait implementation with less constraints:

```rust
impl std::convert::From<i32> for Foo
{
    fn from(value : i32) -> Self {
        Self(value as f32)
    }
}
```

Which then gives me

> conflicting implementations of trait `From<i32>` for type `Foo`

What's the issue here, shouldn't the generic instantiation be discard for `i32` because the type requirement failed, thus allowing another explicit implementation for `From<i32>`?

Comment: _Currently_ `From<i32> for f32` is not implemented, but std may implement it at any time.

Comment: Also, always look at the whole error from `cargo check`: ```note: upstream crates may add a new impl of trait `std::convert::From<i32>` for type `f32` in future versions```.